# flash projector customization

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So lets say I make a game using flash and as3, then I publish it as .exe, would adobe mind if I customized the projector with third party software like resource hacker, like change .exe icon and title from the default flash icon and text "flash player 10", then distribute that .exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a projector you will need a 3rd party tool, but i think you will find that resource hacker won't work in CS6, only in CS5 and earlier.
 It would be best to package the exe with a tool like [MDM Zink](http://multidmedia.com/software/zinc/), where you can cutomize your Window. Since tools like Zink have been round a while and are established i dont think Adobe has any problems with it.

Why dont you publish with AIR? There you have full control over the window(Chrome) and have additional Desktop relevant libraries. And you can package as captive .exe.

Comment: Just making clear/sure, Im not talking about adobe air publishing now... Im talking about flash exe, also called flash projector... Chrome? Can you please explain?

Comment: expanding my earlier comment, can you please explain how I customize it without need of resource hacker or such? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry mate, i read "publish exe" and thought air. i'll update answer

Comment: why I dont use air is because for what I´ve understood, player also needs air to install the game. then I should go through all the hassle of getting distribution rights from adobe to distribute air with my game, then I should make downloader for that air and game, and I also should estimate how many will play it for adobe air distribution rights and ... *sigh* so much easier to just give possible player easy download, like simple .exe he can just straight away download and run.

Comment: You can package an air .exe captive and non-captive. captive includes air runtime in the exe and air doesnt need to be installed. Non captive needs the air runtime, but handles download and update routine itself, so no hassle there either. and you dont need rights from adobe to do so

Comment: I haven´t heard of that before... I use flash CS5.5, does it include this captive and non-captive? if so, how do I make it captive? through as3?

Comment: Not sure if CS5.5 has the captive publish options integratet in the IDE. I think it should. Otherwise you can package it with adt http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html

Comment: soo how do you do this bundle? through command prompt or do I just throw it to my code? im completely lost, and from your link I dont really get what I should actually do....

Comment: through command line! adt is in the Air SDK, read some more here. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd9.html